# Data stored in file is erased after exiting the app

Tags: android

I'm using this code to save data to file and read data from the file:

```
public static void save(FileIO files) {
        BufferedWriter out = null;
        try {

            out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                    files.writeFile(".save")));

            for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
                out.write(Integer.toString(scores[i]));
                out.write("\n");
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
        } finally {
            try {
                if (out != null)
                    out.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }
    }

    public static void load(FileIO files) {
        BufferedReader in = null;
        try {

            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    files.readFile(".save")));

            for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
                scores[i] = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        } finally {
            try {
                if (in != null)
                    in.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }
    }
```

FileIO.java

```
package com.avoidblocks.avoidblocks.framework;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import android.content.SharedPreferences;

public interface FileIO {
    public InputStream readFile(String file) throws IOException;

    public OutputStream writeFile(String file) throws IOException;

    public InputStream readAsset(String file) throws IOException;

    public SharedPreferences getSharedPref();
}
```

I'm calling `save(FileIO files)` and `load(FileIO files)` multiple times in an app and it works fine while I'm in an app, but when I exit the app and start the app again, all data is gone.

Does anyone know how to create that data remains saved even when I exit the app, so that I could restore the data when I start the app again?

Also, is this the right way to save data if I want that saved data is only visible to my app and that after uninstall, all saved data is erased?

Comment: What is `FileIO`? Is this your own class?

Comment: So `FileIO` is an interface. We need to see the implementing class in order to help you. In particular, how are you opening the files which you write to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT-EDIT-EDIT:
ok its your FileIO files variable that looks like it is wrong,
what are you using to get that variable?

should be

```
context.openFileOutput(".save", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
```

for save and

```
context.openFileInput(".save")
```

for load

and it should be FileOutputStream for save and FileInputStream for read instead of FileIO.
and when adding it to the stream just pass that in.

so in your code you should create the BufferedWriter like this:

```
    out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
            context.openFileOutput(".save", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)));
```

and create BufferedReader like this:

```
    in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            context.openFileInput(".save")));
```

==================EDIT: my testing code=================

Ok, I created an activity and made the following two methods and declared an array of ints:

```
    public static int scores[] = {11,12,13,14,15};


    public static void save(Context context) {
        BufferedWriter out = null;

        try {

            out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                    context.openFileOutput(".saveingTest", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)));

            for (int i = 0; i < scores.length; i++) {
                out.write(Integer.toString(scores[i]));
                out.write("\n");
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
        } finally {
            try {
                if (out != null)
                    out.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }
    }

    public static void load(Context context) {
        BufferedReader in = null;
        try {

            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    context.openFileInput(".saveingTest")));

            for (int i = 0; i < scores.length; i++) {
                Log.d("testingApp", "test: " + Integer.parseInt(in.readLine()));
//                scores[i] = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        } finally {
            try {
                if (in != null)
                    in.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }
    }
```

in my onCreate I have the following two lines of code:

```
save(this);
load(this);
```

to test I did the following:

commented out load in onCreate, ran the app, than I removed the comment on load and commented out save in onCreate and i changed the numbers in the scores variable(this is unnecessary but i did it anyway) and ran the app, the result was the int values in scores from the first time the app was run, inside the android log viewer window on eclipse. you can also have buttons that trigger save and load instead if you don't want to comment and run.

try it yourself, it should work, and make sure you are doing the same thing in your actual android app, if it still dose not work you are doing something else wrong and its not an issue with saving the file.

Comment: Doesn't work, I get the same result as with my code.

Comment: ok im at work right now, but i will send more information about my solution when I get home, if you do not get an answer or figure it out by then. also: if you are calling save and read multiple times make sure you are not overwriting the file or saving it before you actually want to or loading before you want to.

Comment: Try a test android app with a button to save and a button to load, test it by: open app, click save, close app, open app, click load and display data, if its correct save and load work, and your problem is something else (possibly you are overwriting the file in the wrong place).